# How to create automatically for every page footer in docx using C#

Tags: c#, footer, wordprocessingml

I am creating a docx and I need a footer (for each page of a document) with timestamp and page (in this format: [present page] of [total pages].
Every post/code I've read online seems to indicate that I must create a footer manually for every page and write the page information manually: is it true? Is it not possible to write code in a way that, appended a footer to the main document, the docx automatically create itself every footer populating it with the right information?

Any advice?

**[UPDATE]**
I am using *DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing* and, following Heinzi's example, I've created a new document, added a footer and than I analyzed the docx by Open XML SDK 2.5: footer is created by this method:

```
private void GeneratePartContent(FooterPart part)
    {
        Footer footer1 = new Footer(){ MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes(){ Ignorable = "w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex w16sdtdh wp14" }  };
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx1", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx3", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx4", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx5", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx6", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx7", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx8", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("aink", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("am3d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w15", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w16cex", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w16cid", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w16", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w16sdtdh", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w16se", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphAddition = "007C3796", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "007C3796", ParagraphId = "5404E3E7", TextId = "621D9DAC" };

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
        ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId(){ Val = "Footer" };

        paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

        Run run1 = new Run();
        FieldChar fieldChar1 = new FieldChar(){ FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Begin };

        run1.Append(fieldChar1);

        Run run2 = new Run();
        FieldCode fieldCode1 = new FieldCode(){ Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
        fieldCode1.Text = " PAGE   \\* MERGEFORMAT ";

        run2.Append(fieldCode1);

        Run run3 = new Run();
        FieldChar fieldChar2 = new FieldChar(){ FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Separate };

        run3.Append(fieldChar2);

        Run run4 = new Run();

        RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
        NoProof noProof1 = new NoProof();

        runProperties1.Append(noProof1);
        Text text1 = new Text();
        text1.Text = "1";

        run4.Append(runProperties1);
        run4.Append(text1);

        Run run5 = new Run();
        FieldChar fieldChar3 = new FieldChar(){ FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.End };

        run5.Append(fieldChar3);

        paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
        paragraph1.Append(run1);
        paragraph1.Append(run2);
        paragraph1.Append(run3);
        paragraph1.Append(run4);
        paragraph1.Append(run5);

        footer1.Append(paragraph1);

        part.Footer = footer1;
    }
```

I copied this method and called

```
FooterPart footerPart1 = mainDocumentPart1.AddNewPart<FooterPart>("rId6");
        GenerateFooterPart1Content(footerPart1);
```

but I have no footer, any advice?

Comment: I just created a 2 page Word file containing a footer, and the source code (= rename to .zip, look at XML files) only contains the footer once, so yes, it's possible. You can look at how Word did it and do it the same way, if you create the XML structure manually. If you use a library to create the docx file, you forgot to tell us which one. :-)

Comment: @Heinzi ok, I see, my new document too, I used a "legacy" document with a lot noise. Now I have a simpler situation to analyze, thanks. Anyway I am using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.